# XSD (bitwise) logic between two attributes

Tags: xsd

Is it possible for XSD to apply (bitwise) logic between two XML attributes?

I hope to catch the following schema violation:

```xml
<parent mask="0x0007">
  <child id="1" value="0x0001"/>
  <child id="2" value="0x0002"/>
  <child id="x" value="0x0010"/> // catch this!
</parent>
```

child x can clearly not be masked by its parent.

In simple logic:

```
if ((value AND mask) != value) then
  # child element is invalid
endif
```

My application can of course catch this during the loading of the XML.
But my application applies schema validation prior to that and it would be grand if we can catch this during that stage.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't. There's no constraining facet that'd let you do that natively, and the usual way to extend this mechanism would be to use XPath through an assertion, but I don't think XPath2 has any bitwise operation either. Maybe you could use some trick (such as a regex) but it would seem much more sane to validate this constraint on the consumer and/or producer of the XSD with a higher level language

Comment: Which version of XSD? 1.0 or 1.1?

Comment: We are still stuck with XSD 1.0, but others might appreciate an answer based on XSD 1.1 if you have it?